# SQL query to find field value that is contained in supplied string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to make an SQL query which will search for a keyword contained in a string.

E.g. The string that is supplied is "The quick brown fox" and the database contains a column 'keywords' and one of the entries has the word 'fox' stored in that column. Is it possible to do a search query that returns all the entries that contain words that are within the string that is supplied?

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL?  They are different.

Comment: It's possible.  What have you tried so far and what were the results of those efforts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE INSTR(keywordField, 'searchString') > 0
```

The above will probably be slow, and depending on your logic it might give false positives; if the search string contains "Foxy", a keywordField "Fox" will be a match.

```
WHERE keywordField IN ('word1', 'word2', 'etc')
```

This will work much fast and more reliably, but you'll have to process your search string and construct the query in code.

(These are both for MySQL specifically, but I can't imagine MS SQL not having similar, if not near identical, functionality.)

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me with the second option what I should do if the number of words are variable? Would I have to loop over an array? Or is there a way to do it in one query?

Comment: By "construct the query in code", I meant process the search string somehow before the query. Looping over an array running a query for each is one possibility; or you could loop over an array to build a single query (the details of which will naturally vary by language and database library used).